# Displaying the string representation of date object in the Watch Expression window

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The console in Chrome Developer Tools used to echo out the string represenation of a Date object. Now it doesn't and isn't very useful - I have to call its toString() method. Also, the Watch Expression window doesn't display the date's value, again not very useful.

Is there anyway to return to how the console and watch window used to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently fixed in WebKit and should be in the tip-of-tree version of Chrome by now:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71605

The best way to request a feature or to report a bug in the Chrome DevTools is to use WebKit bugzilla: http://webkit.org/new-inspector-bug 
or post to Chrome DevTools group: 
http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-developer-tools